# Is there a build in way to group fields from inside a form into groups as a Django buildin?

Tags: python, django, forms

I've got a from like this

```
class myForm(forms.Form):
      name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
      place = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
      email = forms.EmailField()
```

Is there any chance as a build in when accessing the form via the `{{ form }}` placeholder to separate them into groups with setting different background colors or something?

I already found the way on implementing it via a loop inside the template, but wondering whether there is maybe some build in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. The easiest thing is to write out the `{{ field }}` tags manually in your template, surrounding them with divs or fieldsets as required.

Comment: That's half right. He can also just use CSS on their ids (i.e. `#id_name { background-color: red; }`).

Comment: CSS is a good idea for my plans. Thanks -- didn't thought about that